# I am trying to pass a variable into a cronSchedule expression function in java

Tags: java, cron, job-scheduling, quartz

Here is the expression:

```
int month = 8;
    Trigger trigger1 = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("cronTrigger1", "group1")
                .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 57 01 14 month ? 2021"))
                .build();
```

Does any one know how to pass the variable into the .cronSchedule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do

```java
Trigger trigger1 = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("cronTrigger1", "group1")
                .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(String.format("0 57 01 14 %s ? 2021", month)))
                .build();
```

Although I think using one of the static methods in http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.3/index.html like `weeklyOnDayAndHourAndMinute` and the `DateBuilder` constants to make it more readable.

Comment: Thank you! it worked, but ("0 57 01 14 %s ? 2021", month) instead.

Comment: Ah yeah sorry. I edited my answer to be the correct string